# User identity Role

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using asp.net core razor page
I'm spending lot time with this thing that appear easy, but can't find solution.

Create a project and working well, login, register, etc. But Authorization not working with roles. Roles are created and:

But always return Access Denied when trying to access:

Now I create two roles 1-Admin 2-User in the AspNetUserRoles database
[image: as pic]

[image: ""]

and this is my code

```
   [Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
    public class AdminModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

and in startup is

```
      services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin",
                     policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            });
```

the problem is always access denied?

Answer (score 1):

The `NormalizedName` of the Role should be upper case - ADMIN. It's best to use the `RoleManager.CreateAsync` API to create roles rather than adding them manually to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I was make a mistake it was fill AspNetUserRole and AspNetRole manually, and the right way is to fill auto throw register page.